# lua alchemy has serious performance issue, is there any alternatives?

Tags: actionscript-3, lua

I ran empty lua script that only includes empty function 100 times and it tooks more than 100ms which is unacceptable for me. Is there any alternatives i can use?

Comment: does luaJIT work for you?

Comment: Could You be more specific for those people who haven't used Lua Alchemy, for what functionality are You seeking alternatives, please?

Comment: @kamiccolo lua alchemy is a kind of way using lua in actionscript. My request is simple as i described above. Think about you have 100 game object and all of them has own lua script, even though all lua scripts are empty, just running of them costs almost 150ms which means very low fps.

Comment: @eerrzz Adobe Flash Is not something like C++ that can run smoothly with even 1k objects having 100 lua files for each, If you want to make a lua game with adobe flash, I suggest you to make less objects than possible or run the codes once needed, not every tick.

Answer (score 0):

Lua Alchemy Is a port for Adobe Flash, You can't do anything about the speed of It except managing your scripts. Flash Isn't a fast language that runs smoothly on user's system, On C#/C/C++ or Java you can run lua smoothly without any problems. If you're hooking your functions to run every time that an event happens then I suggest you to not, It's better to run something every 1 sec rather than running it 100 times every milliseconds.